# Automatically show correct timing from days in HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

A person Has Office hours Monday, Wednesday and Friday: 7:00 am - 7:00pm and on Tuesday and Thursday his office hours are 10:00 am – 9:00 pm. I would like the the drop down menu to only show 7:00 AM - 7:00 PM if the selected date is a Monday, Wednesday or Friday. And only show timings from 10:00 am – 9:00 pm if selected date on form is Tuesday or Thursday.

```
<form action="/submission.php" method="POST">
    <Label>Date Of Appointment</label>
    <input type="date" name="dateOfAppointment">
    <br><br>
    <Label>Time Of Appointment</label>
    <select name="appointmentTiming">
      <option value="7:00 AM">7:00 AM</option>
      <option value="8:00 AM">8:00 AM</option>
      <option value="9:00 AM">9:00 AM</option>
      <option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
      <option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
      <option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
      <option value="1:00 PM">1:00 PM</option>
      <option value="2:00 PM">2:00 PM</option>
      <option value="3:00 PM">3:00 PM</option>
      <option value="4:00 PM">4:00 PM</option>
      <option value="5:00 PM">5:00 PM</option>
      <option value="6:00 PM">6:00 PM</option>
      <option value="8:00 PM">8:00 PM</option>
      <option value="9:00 PM">9:00 PM</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
</form>
```

Comment: In `dateOfAppointment` field you want user to enter select date? then depending on date(day selected) you want to show timings in another dropdown?

Comment: dateOfAppointment has type="date" which automatically give you a small calender when you click on it, and you can select your date from there; in google chrome. I want the appointmentTiming to automatically detect the user's selected date and show hours according to that day. For example if choosen date is a 12/22/2018 and is a friday, I want the appointmentTiming to show 7:00AM to 7:00PM hours.

Comment: Did you even try to solve the mentioned problem using your own JS coding, You're only showing HTML show the JavaScripting you did then this community will help you more. Show the community that have done some effort to solve it by your self with out directly asking what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this code:

```
    <form action="/submission.php" method="POST">
        <Label>Date Of Appointment</label>
        <input id="date" type="date" name="dateOfAppointment">
        <br><br>
        <Label>Time Of Appointment</label>
        <select id="hours" name="appointmentTiming">

        </select>
        <br><br>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
    var now = new Date();
    var today = now.getFullYear() + '-' + (now.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + 
       now.getDate();
       $('#date').val(today);
       changeHours();
     });

    date = document.getElementById('date');
    date.addEventListener('change', changeHours)
function changeHours(){

      var day = new Date( date.value).getDay();

      dropdown = document.getElementById('hours');
      dropdown.innerHTML = '';
      if (day==1 || day==3 || day==5) {
        start = 7;
        hours = 12;
      }
      if (day==2 || day == 4) {
        start = 10;
        hours = 11;
      }

      for(i=0; i<=hours;i++ ){
        time = start + i;
        option = '<option value="'+time+':00 AM">'+time+':00 AM</option>';
        if (time>=12) {
          time= time-12;
          option = '<option value="'+time+':00 PM">'+time+':00 PM</option>';
        }
        dropdown.innerHTML += option;
      }

    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following JS code to get the selected day:

```
var selectedDateEle = document.getElementsByName('dateOfAppointment')[0];
var selectedDay;
selectedDateEle.onchange = function(){
    selectedDay = new Date(selectedDateEle.value).getDay();
}
```

This will give you an integervalue for the day, with Sun = 0 and Sat = 6.
You can use this value further to change the dropdown.